# What kind of houseplant is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants

What kind of houesplant is this and in what climate does it best grow in?[image]

Comment: I agree it looks to me like Nolina recurvata as mentioned in the previous question. The tree 'trunk' is the water store, so this likes an arid climate and not overwatered. Sorry an old name used, see name noted in answer below

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Beaucarnea recurvata - we used to have one years ago.

Comment: This only answers half of the question.